# How do I promote text fields to custom form properties in Adobe Livecycle?

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am new to Adobe Livecycle and have created an XML dynamic form using Livecycle Designer ES4. I am looking for a way to promote a text field from the form to a custom property in the Forms Properties. An example would be the user fills in the field "TextField20" and after making that entry the custom property "Project Objective" in the forms properties is updated to reflect that information. Is it possible to promote metadata like this in Livecycle or is there another solution that I may not be thinking of? I tried researching online, but couldn't find anything related, which may be due to searching the wrong Adobe terminology/taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about Variable tab in the form properties dialog.
In which case every property added creates a node in the form hierarchy with the name of the variables.
You only have to set this variable on the exit event of TextField20.

```
nameOfTheProperty.value = this.rawValue;
```

And that's it !